# How to make larger brackets in maths equations?

Tags: math-mode

When I use regular brackets () in Overleaf, they come out a regular size, but the size doesn't change if I have larger than regular terms inside the brackets. Do you know how I can control the size of the brackets?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to the site!

Comment: You might be interested in reading https://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it few ways:

1. using `\left...\right`
2. using `\Biggl\biggl\bigl...\bigr\biggr\Biggr`

But without seeing any image or your `MWE` give suggestion is more difficult...